# CRgn ScreenToClient

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have several Custom Drawn CStatic which use `SetWindowRgn` to give each of them an irregular (non-rectangular) shape. I need to Invalidate a the region behind each of these Controls `OnEraseBkgnd`, for which I would like to use `CWnd::InvalidateRgn` on the parent `CDialog` however I need to translate the `CRgn` into the coordinates of the parent. I would like to have something like `Cwnd::ScreenToClient(CRgn *)` but as far as I can see no such thing exists.

How do I get the equivalent of `CWnd::ScreenToClient` that takes a CRgn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Split `CRgn` region into rectangles using [`GetRegionData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6f4fdaa%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- `ScreenToClient` individual rectangles
- Combine the output back into region using `CreateFromData`

An alternate option is [`CRgn::OffsetRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a100kw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to offet the region using the distance obtained from `ScreenToClient` for an individual point.